# How does Quen work?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I know how to activate Quen, and I am aware that it absorbs damage during the time it is active (about 40 seconds).

Now, the manual says:

> .. the Quen absorbs all damage directed at you, and the upgraded version reflects
>   50% of the damage at the enemy ..

Is it time-based, that is, am I protected 100% during this time, or is there a maximum damage level it can absorb, after which I am unprotected?

Because I am pretty sure my vitality did drop while in battle with the Quen up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quen sign absorbs all damage as long as it is active. But each hit reduces the amount of time the shield is active. If you pay attention you can see the time remaining at the top of the screen decreasing when you're hit. But as long as Quen is active, 100% of the damage is absorbed.

Comment: I see it now, so the manual is right, but it doesn't tell us that damage chips away at remaining time.

Comment: In addition to Fabian's answer above--

One of the help bubbles suggests that Quen is more powerful in the rain, but I'm not sure in what regard